# Getting Value from a Custom Prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble getting the value of a custom prompt in PHP. I actually made a custom prompt that consist of two input boxes and stored it in a variable. When I clicked a button I'll just call it. I have no problem with this for its working well.

```
var popup = "div id='overlay'>
 <div id='box_frame'>
  <div id='box'><a href='javascript:closeDialog()'>close</a>
     <h2>Edit Material</h2>
     <h1>"+projName+"</h1>
    <label>Material</label>
    <input name='boxMatName' type='textbox' value='"+matName+"'   disabled />
    <br>
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input id='boxEstVal' type='textbox' value='"+estQty+"'  />
    <br>
    <button onclick='javascript:saveDesc()'>Save</button>
    <div id='try'></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

";

I tried this to get the value from the prompts:

```
        function saveDesc(){
    var mat = ('#boxMatName').val();
    var est = ('#boxMatName').text();

    alert(mat+est);
```

However,  I am not getting any results.  Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you give another id to your input:

```
var popup = "div id='overlay'>
<div id='box_frame'>
<div id='box'><a href='javascript:closeDialog()'>close</a>
 <h2>Edit Material</h2>
 <h1>"+projName+"</h1>
<label>Material</label>
<input name='boxMatName' id="boxMatName" type='textbox' value='"+matName+"'   disabled />
<br>
<label>Quantity</label>
<input id='boxEstVal' type='textbox' value='"+estQty+"'  />
<br>
<button onclick='javascript:saveDesc()'>Save</button>
 <div id='try'></div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

then, this should work.

```
function saveDesc(){
  var mat = $('#boxMatName').val();
  var est = $('#boxEstVal').val();
  alert(mat + ' - ' + est);
}
```

by the way, did you include the jquery in the head of your html file?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: oow.its working.i missed the $ sign.thank you very much sir @doniyor

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<input>` so you need `val()` and not `text()`:

```
var mat = $("input[name=boxMatName]").val();
var est = document.getElementById('boxEstVal').value; // or $('#boxEstVal').val();
```

Comment: Your second line will result in error. `document.getElementById` will return native DOM element, it does not contain `val()` method.

Comment: @chris the second line should be `var est = $("#boxEstVal").val();`.

Comment: @chris I corrected the code. val() belongs to jQuery while the second line was pure js.

Comment: i've edited the code.and still not working sir @KonstantinD-Infragistics D